# Send uncompressed if the Accept-Encoding does not include "Identity"?

Tags: http, http-headers

If a http client does not explicitly request Identity in the Accept-Encoding field, may the data from the server still be sent uncompressed- or MUST it compress the data using one of the requestor's Accept-Encoding types (and set "Content-Encoding" accordingly)?

In other words, is "Identity" always a valid, implied option even when not stated explicitly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

["The "identity" content-coding is always acceptable, unless
         specifically refused because the Accept-Encoding field includes
         "identity;q=0", or because the field includes "*;q=0" and does
         not explicitly include the "identity" content-coding. If the
         Accept-Encoding field-value is empty, then only the "identity"
         encoding is acceptable."](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.3)

So, yes, you can reply with *identity* on `Accept-encoding: gzip, deflate` for instance, but *not* on `Accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, identity;q=0"`.